# FFMPEG Command Freezes

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

I'm using this command to concatenate multiple mp3 files

```
ffmpeg -i http://dev-vigor.s3.eu-de.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/vigor_cdn_1588425465517.mp3 -i http://dev-vigor.s3.eu-de.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/vigor_cdn_1588425920670.mp3  -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" -codec:a libmp3lame 5eab0137ab513179f4427b79.mp3 -y
```

the command works perfectly fine when I run it on my local system but when i use it on the server where it's supposed to work, it freezes after fetching the first file or a little into the second one.
I'm using windows 10 on my local system and Centos 8 on the server.

Comment: Show the complete log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after i gave the server more resources, apparently there wasn't enough memory for ffmpeg to operate? which is a bit weird, but it works fine now.